# LocationManager locations

Tags: swift, position, locationmanager

I have a list that is populated with data from an API. So basically the process is like this:

When the user opens the application I do:

```
if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 20
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
```

Then in my `func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])` I call the API to get data.

But the issue is that `func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])` can be called up to 5-6 times sometimes so there will be a lot of API calls and if I only get one position the chance is big that I get a location that can be far away from the user.

Any ideas of how to solve this issue? I basically want the best location and make as few API calls as possible, preferable one.

Comment: Just a couple of thoughts: (a) throttle your own app to make a maximum of *n* requests per minute; (b) each `CLLocation` has a `horizontalAccuracy` property. If it's too large, ignore the location

Comment: Good comment @CodeDifferent, regarding the idea with `horizontalAccuracy` what is the lowest accuracy location manager accepts? So that I know what I can ignore.

Comment: You have to experiment to find out. [The National Library of Medicine](https://communityhealthmaps.nlm.nih.gov/2014/07/07/how-accurate-is-the-gps-on-my-smart-phone-part-2/) cites a study that says iPhone 3G accuracy is about 8 meters. That was in 2009 though.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you want avoid may API calls at `func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])` you need consider some controls:

- Create a time interval between received locations
- "Improve" your `horizontalAccuracy` and `distanceFilter` values

Keep in mind that always you need avoid:

- Avoid nil locations
- Invalid locations
- Invalid locations
- Out-of-order location
- Cached locations (before you start the locationManager)

Code Example:

```
protocol MyLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationControllerDidUpdateLocation(location: CLLocation)
}

final class MyLocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var oldLocation: CLLocation?
    let kTimeFilter = Double(10)                  //avoid locations for each kTimeFilter seconds
    let kValidDistanceToOldLocation = Double(100)  //avoid location less than kValidDistanceToOldLocation meters
    var startDate: NSDate?
    var delegate: MyLocationManagerDelegate?


    func isValidLocation(newLocation newLocation: CLLocation?, oldLocation: CLLocation?) -> Bool {

        // avoid nil locations
        if newLocation == nil {
            return false
        }

        //avoid invalid locations
        if newLocation!.coordinate.latitude == 0 || newLocation!.coordinate.longitude == 0 {
            return false
        }

        //avoid invalid locations
        if (newLocation!.horizontalAccuracy < 0){
            return false
        }

        if oldLocation != nil {

            let distance = newLocation!.distanceFromLocation(oldLocation!)

            if fabs(distance) < kValidDistanceToOldLocation {
                return false
            }

            //avoid out-of-order location.
            let secondsSinceLastPoint = newLocation!.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceDate(oldLocation!.timestamp)
            if secondsSinceLastPoint < 0 || secondsSinceLastPoint < kTimeFilter {
                return false
            }
        }

        //avoid cached locations (before you start the locationManager)
        let secondsSinceManagerStarted = newLocation!.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceDate(startDate!)
        if secondsSinceManagerStarted < 0 {
            return false
        }

        return true
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let newLocation = locations.last

        if isValidLocation(newLocation: newLocation, oldLocation:oldLocation) || oldLocation == nil {
            self.delegate?.locationControllerDidUpdateLocation(newLocation!)
            oldLocation = newLocation
        }

    }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController, MyLocationManagerDelegate {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let location = MyLocationManager()
        location.delegate = self

    }

    func locationControllerDidUpdateLocation(location: CLLocation) {
        //Api Call
    }

}
```